# Android make sdk fails with error cannot find -lz

Tags: android, android-sdk-2.3

I am getting an error when I try to build sdk logs below:

```
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/tsan-arm-linux
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_drd-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_massif-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_tsan-arm-linux.so
: out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/dbus-monitor
: out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/dbus-send
: out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/opcontrol
: out/target/product/generic/system/xbin/oprofiled
host Executable: aapt (out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/aapt)
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/aapt_intermediates/aapt] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that maybe you have not installed all necessary tools to build sdk. Check at this [webpage](http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html).